# Correlation between tasks, sub-projects and configurations

Tags: gradle

I have next structure for my project:

```
Root
 |- A
 |- C (depends on A)
 \- B (depends on A)
```

For all of sub-projects we use own plugin for generate-resources: https://github.com/terma/gradle-sqlj-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/github/terma/sqljgradleplugin/SqljPlugin.groovy the task from plugin doesn't depend on any however JavaCompile task depends on it

When I build my project in build log I see:

```
:A:myPluginTask
:B:myPluginTask
:C:myPluginTask
:A:compileJava 
:A:processResources
:A:classes
:B // next normal build way
```

Question why Gradle execute my plugin task for all sub-projects before java tasks? And why it execute java tasks in normal way first all java tasks for A than B ...?

Optional question how Gradle build task execution tree, separated for each project or cross projects?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

All that can be said (and relied upon) is that Gradle will choose a task order that satisfies the declared task relationships (`dependsOn`, `mustRunAfter`, `shouldRunAfter`, `finalizedBy`). All execution dependencies are between tasks (not projects), and it's common that tasks belonging to different projects will get executed in alternation (or in parallel if `--parallel` is used). There is a single task execution graph for the whole build.

Comment: Thx for answer. Very interesting. However I can't find any example how to setup cross project task dependencies? I found that for example Java plugin use dependency on SourceSet however it's still related to same project.

Comment: Typically, Gradle infers these task dependencies automatically, for example from project (artifact) dependencies. Otherwise, you can do `foo.dependsOn ":A:myPluginTask"`.

Comment: So if I have my plugin with one task X `project A(X -> javaCompile -> classes -...> build)` and `project B (compile project dependency on A) (same tasks list)` what info Gradle needs to infers correct task exection graph?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer this question. Which problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps time for a new question.

Comment: You are right, I tried to understand general mechanism to fix my question, however no luck, so here my detailed question (thx): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268220/add-task-to-gradle-execution-graph